# In rooted device detect if an outgoing call has been answered

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing a **system app** in which I need to capture the outgoing call **answer/reject** events. Could you advice on how to achieve this in a rooted device please ?  Problem with **TelephonyManager** class is that there is no notification of when outgoing call has answered.
This is crucial to my app. My target device is android **4.4**(kitkat).

Some thing like this app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.yutouji0917.callvibrator.ad

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution for this? I am also working on a rooted phone.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must register broadcast receiver for listening phone events like incoming, outgoing call, hang up events and don't forget to define broadcast in manifest file.

Here i am attaching a link that will help you to implement your code
http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/detect-incoming-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And

Comment: Vaibhav I need to know whether outgoing call is answered or not. Above code will not catch any event when outgoing call is answered.